# Xamarin Audio players not working in Galaxy S8

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am trying to get a shoutcast URL (.stream) to stream audio in a cross-platform application. I've started with the Android app first and I cannot get the audio playing on the test device Samsung Galaxy S8.

However, the audio players work fine within the Emulator. If it weren't for the test device I would've assumed everything was working.

I've tried using "the local MediaPlayer" and "Plugin.MediaManager": Both work in the Emulator but none on the device. I have enabled the permissions required in the manifest: `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE`, `INTERNET`, `MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROLS`, `RECORD_AUDIO`, `WAKE_LOCK`, `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

(using MediaManager plugin)

in MainActivy:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
.....
 CrossMediaManager.Current.Init(this);
.....
}
```

```
public class StreamingService: IStreaming.IStreaming
    {

        bool IsPrepared = false;

        public async void Play()
        {
            await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play("http://someUrl/stream");
        }

        public void Pause()
        {
            CrossMediaManager.Current.Pause();
        }

        public void Stop()
        {

            CrossMediaManager.Current.Stop();
            IsPrepared = false;
        }

        public int getResponse()
        {

            if (CrossMediaManager.Current.IsPlaying())
                return 1;
            else
                return 0;
        }
    }
```

If I look at the data usage for the app on the device it is set to 0kb after a few tries it goes up by the kb currently at 3.24kb data usage. It doesnt appear that the media player is trying to access the stream, or can even access the stream.

Comment: I've added the following:
```c#
 player.Error += (sender, args) => {
                //playback error
                Console.WriteLine("Error in playback resetting: " + args.What);
                Stop();//this will clean up and reset properly.
            };
```

And the print out is: Media ERROR Unknown..
I presume it is because the audio type cannot be recognized. the stream is streaming is file format AAC

Comment: I also changed the above code to use MediaPlayer and not the CrossMediaManager - Im desperate for help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a nuget package: LibVLCSharp.Forms

in the Main application created a class:

```
using LibVLCSharp.Shared;

public class RadioStream
    {
        readonly LibVLC _libVLC;
        readonly MediaPlayer _mp;

        public RadioStream()
        {
            if (DesignMode.IsDesignModeEnabled) return;

            Core.Initialize();

            _libVLC = new LibVLC();

            _mp = new MediaPlayer(_libVLC);
        }

        public void Init()
        {
            _mp.Media = new Media(_libVLC, "http://url/stream", FromType.FromLocation);

            _mp.Media.AddOption(":no-video");

        }


        public void Play(bool play)
        {
            if (play)
                _mp.Play();
            else _mp.Pause();
        }

        public bool isPlaying()
        {
            if (_mp.IsPlaying == false)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }

    }
```

And its working!

In a while loop I check the isPlaying() that allows me to set the status of the stream and display accordingly.

Its simple at the moment, and stops playing when the internet state changes. But the above is working for simple playback.